# Make HTML dropdown to be above all page content

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Im using that dropdown widget from http://www.w3schools.com/ :

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the dropdown is not above and hide it, it overlap
Show Image: https://s24.postimg.org/vitjpspv9/image.png
What CSS i need ? Thx.

Comment: That the URL: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: Try to create jsfiddle. You have just added HTML code. Add specific css and javascript for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the layers using z-index.

add the css property:

```
z-index: 4;
```

keep increasing the number if it is still overlapping.
this should allow the black box to come to the front.

Comment: Great, Work, Thx.